# How to set a time-based fetch policy in apollo client for graphql queries?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to use Apollo client to cache Grapql query results. [I reviewed  the fetch policies](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#fetchpolicy) from the docs but I could not find a way to use a cache based policy with expiration.
In my code I have:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  ssrMode: typeof window === "undefined",
  errorPolicy: "all",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    },
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "cache-first",
    },
  },
});
```

The `cache-first` policy does what I am looking for but it does not expire. Is there a way to make the policy dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of hard to understand your use case, as a lot of details are missing.

However, I think what your are looking for is the [cache evict](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/garbage-collection/) functionality. Put that into a `setTimeout` to clear the cached data after a given timeout.

If you want to clear the cache only if the data has not been accessed for a while, you need to combine it with a `clearTimeout`.

I dont think there is a solution with just a fetch policy, they are rather unflexible.